# Try Statement Within for Loop not working python

Tags: python

I have the script below, what I am finding that if my Try statement is satisfied, the whole iteration of the first loop will end and it will just go into the next loop iteration.

What I want to happen is it the, if statement, is satisfied, it then just back to the elif within the for loop that it sits within.

So essentially I want to go

1. For loop.
2. Then try if something works (I know some wont)
3. Then go back into a for loop (and all the subsequent loops will still work.

Ideally I would structure this as: for loop- try statement- for loop, but essentially I am asking the same question as when that happens to, the loop also breaks out.

Thaankyou, Sam

```
# LOOP OVER THE DICTIONARIES (CSV LINE DATA) AND PULL UP THE PARAMETER KEY TO MATCH

tester = []

updatefamilyname = IN[6]
typename_input01_value = IN[7]
typename_input02_value = IN[8]

for datarow_dict in Data_DictionaryList:


    # Get matching value from data row dictionary

    Matching_Value = str(datarow_dict[parameter_key_tomatch])
    #test.append(parameter_key_tomatch)
    #test.append(Matching_Value)

    try: 
        Get_Matching_Value_LongIndex = Base_MatchingWalls_Dict[Matching_Value]
        Split_Index = Get_Matching_Value_LongIndex.split(indexplacesplit)[1]
        MatchedWall = Base_MatchingWalls[int(Split_Index)]
        #test.append(MatchedWall)
        #test.append("here2")

        for para_key, para_value in datarow_dict.items():
            #ResultOutput.append(para_key)
            #ResultOutput.append(typename_input01_value)
            #test.append(para_key)
            #test.append(para_value)

            # We then say if the paramter key is the same as the matching key, open the following
            if para_key == parameter_key_tomatch:
                #test.append("inside")
                ResultOutput.append(para_key + " equal to " + para_value)

                # Set New Family Type Name Value                
                #if para_key == typename_input01_key:
                    #typename_input01_value = para_value
                    #tester.append("inside link")

                #elif para_key == typename_input02_key:
                    #typename_input02_value = para_value

                #else:
                    #print ("go")

            elif para_key != parameter_key_tomatch:
                ResultOutput.append(para_key)   
                print ("not here")
                #ResultOutput.append(para_key)  
                #TestParameter_ = testparavalue(MatchedWall, para_key, para_value)      

                #else:
                    #pass

            # We then say, if its not the same, this is when we want to do some things, could be where we change the family name if we change the name of the name and number
            else:
                print ("ouside exception")
                #ResultOutput.append("else why")

    if updatefamilyname == "Yes":
        ResultOutput.append("update name accepted")     
        print ("yes")



        # THIS IS WHERE WE COULD PASS IN THE OTHER ONE TO MATCH TO FORM THE CHANGE IN FAMILY TYPE NAME


            #typename_input01_value
            #typename_input01_value
            # This is where we bring in 

    # Anything where matching para does not have a corresponding wall type
    except:
        print ("here")
        ResultOutput.append(Matching_Value)
```

Comment: where is your `except` block?

Comment: Format your code with proper indentation

Comment: You've put the for loop inside the try.  To get the results you want, put the try as the first statement inside the for loop.  You'll also need a second try block for the GetValue part of what you are trying to protect that comes before the for loop.

Comment: @Sheri I have added the last part in. I want to have the second for loop after I have done the try. So ideally I would have the main for loop, then a try and then a second for loop as two separate items.